# jquery time ago of server

Tags: php, jquery, timeago

server time : 15:00
time ago : 15:10

i wanna get this message [10 minutes ago]

but my laptop time is : 15:30 
so i get [30 minutes ago]

Is there a solution ???

This is the code :

```
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("time.timeago").timeago();
        });
    </script>

<time style="float:right;margin:-20px 0 0 0;" class="timeago" 
      datetime="<?php echo $c_date; ?>"><?php echo $c_date; ?></time>
```

Comment: JavaScript is client-side. You'll have to use AJAX to get time from the server.

Comment: If it is a dynamic datetime that may change and you want to keep in sync with the server (e.g. "The last time that action X was executed was..."), I'd go with AJAX; if it's a fixed datetime that will not change over time (e.g. "This post was written..."), AJAX seems unnecessary as you will have all the data at the moment the page is loaded (server time, client time, action time = c_date), and you'd only need to apply the time difference between server and client time to the c_date time)